# What does this echo shell command do?

Tags: bash, shell, bash-scripting

I am solving some C.T.F questions and came across this command,

```
echo $'\e(0'
```

What is the use of this command?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: It switches the terminal to box drawing mode, making lowercase text look like ┌─┘.

---

In bash, `$' ... '` is a mode of quoting that interprets C-style escape characters (such as `\e`, `\n`, `\t`). The quoted string `$'\e(0'` therefore results in three bytes, 0x1B 0x28 0x30 (ESC, "(", "0").

Sequences starting with 0x1B/ESC have special meaning when written (echo'd) to a terminal (e.g. `\e[A` moves cursor up, `\e[…m` sets text formatting) and similarly special keys are read as sequences starting with ESC.

A large (but still not entirely complete) list of escape sequences recognized by various terminals can be found [on Xterm's website](http://rtfm.etla.org/xterm/ctlseq.html). According to this list, `\e(…` i.e. `ESC ( …` chooses the *character set* for the G0 slot, i.e. for regular text.

Before Unicode/UTF-8 (and other multibyte character sets and encodings), most computers and terminals directly mapped each byte value to a character, and in order to display more than ~256 different characters VT100-compatible terminals would recognize escape sequences to switch the *mapping* of byte→character.

According to the Xterm table, `ESC ( 0` tells the terminal to use character set 0 which is named "DEC Special Character and Line Drawing Set", commonly known as the [alternate character set](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/alternate_charset/). It includes such characters as `◆ ▒ ␉ ␌ ␍ ␊ ° ± ␤ ␋ ┘ ┐ ┌ └ ┼ ⎺⎻─⎼⎽ ├ ┤ ┴ ┬ │ ≤ ≥ π ≠ £` and is still commonly used to draw boxes and dialog windows if the terminal doesn't understand Unicode.

For example, `echo $'\e(0jklmn\e(B'` would switch to the ACS, print `┘┐┌└┼`, and switch back.